# Why are headings beyond level 6 not displaying in my Office Open XML document?

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, docx

I am trying to print headers like Header1 (1), Header2 (1.1) etc. The headers are printing till level 6 Header6 (1.1.1.1.1.1) but unable to print 7th (1.1.1.1.1.1.1), 8th, 9th level.
Below is what I've tried. Here I have used `<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc. from a loop creating an HTML table.

```csharp
var dataToStore = new string[] { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", "Test7", "Test8", "Test9" };
string htmltext = "";
int headerCnt = 1;

foreach (var data in dataToStore)
{
    htmltext += "<table border='1'><tr><td colspan='2'><h" + headerCnt + " style='font-family:Calibri;color:blue;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='" + data + "'>" + data + " : " + data + "</a></h" + headerCnt + "></td></tr>";
    htmltext += "</table><br/><br/>";
    headerCnt++;
}
var mainhtml = "<html><head></head><body>" + htmltext + "</body></html>";

var altChunkId = "AltChunkId1";           
var destFilePath = $@"provide Path\New Microsoft Word Document.docx";
var byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(destFilePath);
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    using (var wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
    {
        var document = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document;
        var mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;
        var paragraphList = document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>().ToList();                   
       
        //Import data as html content using Altchunk
        var chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Html, altChunkId);

        using (var chunkStream = chunk.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (var stringWriter = new StreamWriter(chunkStream, Encoding.UTF8)) 
            {
                stringWriter.Write(mainhtml);
            }
        }
        var altChunk = new AltChunk();
        altChunk.Id = altChunkId;

        mainPart.Document.Body.InsertAt(altChunk, 1);
        wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart.Settings.Append(
            new UpdateFieldsOnOpen { Val = true }
        );
    }
    // Save the file 
    File.WriteAllBytes(destFilePath, stream.ToArray());
}
```

Note: If a new word doc is created and no headers present, we need to add header styling to the styles section

Comment: You're saying that the values in `dataToStore` beyond `"Test6"` aren't displayed?  HTML heading elements only go up to `<h6>`.  The mentions of hierarchical heading text such as `1.1` and `2.1.1.1.1.1` are confusing since those aren't present in your code and would seem to use a different notion of "levels".

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews Edited my question its 1.1. series. Values beyond 6 will be displayed but headers 7,8,9 isn't being printed. In this case "Test7 : Test7" will be printed but without header value 1.1.1.1.1.1.1. It should print "1.1.1.1.1.1.1 Test7 : Test7"